# MicroUpdate 1.1 for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise from its MSDN-downloaded .ISO image on a brand-new Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit machine, the Setup ended up displaying this error message:

> MicroUpdate 1.1 for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 : This product did not
>   download successfully: Signature verification failed on downloaded
>   file.  URL: 
>   'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14vsuldr&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=24723.02&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=enu_MicroUpdate1.1_iOOB&o2=enu&o3=patch\kb3110221&o4=VS14-KB3110221.exe'

The funny this is that if you navigate to that URL, there is no exe at that location.

I then downloaded the .ISO image for the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and confirmed its SHA1 value. I ran that on my system, and the same error message above appeared.

What is this MicroUpdate 1.1 and why is it not getting applied? As of this writing, no Google entries have been written about this particular issue, leaving me somewhat flummoxed.

Comment: No solution, but also getting the same thing.

Comment: Just saw the same error myself.  Haven't yet done the reboot after the main install, but I plan to try a "manual download and installation from the Microsoft Download Center" afterward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search for kb3110221 you will find a link to [KB 3110221: Servicing Update to Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50376).

On that page there is a working download link and a link to [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 servicing update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9fe1e585-e0f5-4688-be35-6b133ac192e0), which explains

> This servicing update provides fixes to Visual Studio 2015 that address four high-impact bugs that were either found by the product team or reported from the community. This update can be installed only on machines that have Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 applied. All four fixes are included in the one update installer and can't be consumed individually. The fixes that are provided in this update will also be released in the next Visual Studio 2015 update.

and

> This update is available for manual download and installation from the Microsoft Download Center.

Comment: That's crazy because as of yesterday there was not a single Google hit when I typed "KB3110221" into the Google search engine! I'm glad to see that it now is there. Also, I now tried the path to the EXE above, and it seems that it now resolves. So I suppose there was a period of time between the completion of my VS 2015 setup and your reply during which Microsoft has not yet posted the EXE or was not aware of the issue. All's well that ends well! Thank you!

Comment: The saga continues: See my related post: Setup Blocked GB3110221

Comment: @Jazimov It worked when I tested it here on W7 Pro x64, so it *can* work. I'll take a look at your newer question [Setup Blocked GB3110221](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34297703/1115360).

Answer (score 1):

This should now be fixed (as of ~10:30am PST on Dec 15th). Internally, when we tested this before we published yesterday, we were running with our internal test redirect server in place and didn't realize it. Just this morning, we have correctly mapped the necessary links so that this problem should not happen going forward.

If you've already installed, then Andrew's suggested fix is the best way to get the MicroUpdate 1.1.

Eric Knox, Visual Studio engineering manager

Comment: Eric, good to know. Also, would you kindly also review my related post cited above? Thanks.