# Setup Blocked KB3110221

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Related to my previous post:
[MicroUpdate 1.1 for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295612/microupdate-1-1-for-visual-studio-2015-update-1?noredirect=1#comment56334636_34295612)

When I download and run the Micro Update 1.1 for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, I receive this error message in a Visual Studio window that states "Setup Blocked":

> KB3110221 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your
>   computer.

In the log file is this entry, soon before the Stop Block condition:

> MUX:  Failed to download the update xml file from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=646050 Setup will not be updated.

I'm going to guess that Microsoft still is working on getting this Micro Update 1.1 to work...

Comment: As it was a "failed to download" error, it might work if you try it again in a few minutes. +1 for actually doing the research into the log file :)

Comment: Thank you... Still not working. Will also start from clean boot just to be sure nothing else is awry. Once again, this is a very clean install: Fresh Win 7 64, all updates, VS 2015 Ent install, VS 2015 Update 1. That's all this computer has ever seen. Can't get much cleaner than this!

Comment: Clean boot--made no difference. Still get "Setup Blocked" likely due to the log-file cited issue.

Comment: Well, I just tried the VS2015 Update 1 on Windows 10, and it installed KB3110221 *on its own* with no complaints at all. I can only suggest that you run [SFC.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833).

Comment: Perhaps and perhaps not: The Microsoft manager responsible for this is apparently actively doing things on the Microsoft end to fix these issues (as he indicated on the previous thread) so it might simply be a timing issue (I hit the server when it wasn't working; you hit it when it was). I'll try again and will let you know.

Comment: My issue remains but remember that I already applied Update 1. So at this point I'm trying to apply ONLY the Micro Update 1.1. If running VS14-KB3110221.EXE causes the Setup Blocked error, I'd still like to find a resolution to that which does not require me to apply Update 1 again or to roll-that-back and then apply Update 1 again. In theory (and by design, I would think) "micro-update 1.1" as VS14-KB3110221.EXE should be able to be applied at any time following Update 1 without receiving such a cryptic "Setup Blocked" error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file line you referenced is benign. It simply means that setup went online to see if there was a newer version of the same installer (a mechanism for servicing), but it didn't find an updated version.

The real issue is the KB3110221 does not apply. That should only happen if VS Update 1 is not on your computer. Did your install of VSUpdate 1 succeed or fail?

Comment: Eric, thanks. I suppose it "succeeded"... But it terminated with the message: "MicroUpdate 1.1 for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 : This product did not download successfully: Signature verification failed on downloaded file. URL: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14vsuldr&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=24723.02&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=enu_MicroUpdate1.1_iOOB&o2=enu&o3=patch\kb3110221&o4=VS14-KB3110221.exe'". When I saw that the exe didn't download, I tried to get it manually. Now that I have it, it won't install without showing "Setup Blocked". So what does that mean?

Comment: Overall, MicroUpdate 1.1 is techniclaly optional. And as long as the original dialog said "Setup Completed" instead of "Setup Failed", you should be able to use Update 1.
If Update 1 succeeded though, I'd expect the MicroUpdate to install correctly. So my best guess is that the original Update 1 process did not succeed. And if that's the case, then it's by design that MicroUpdate would not apply.

Comment: My log file indicates: "MUX:  Stop Block: NoApplicableUpdates : KB3110221 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer." I"m not crazy about the use of the word "or": If the update does not apply, then Setup should just complete. But to say "Setup Blocked" when the underlying condition is that the setup doesn't apply is rather deceiving and alarming and doesn't let me know whether it doesn't apply or that it is blocked...

Comment: I get what you're saying (sort of) but It certainly begs the question: What exactly does MicroUpdate 1.1 do? Are you suggesting that Update 1 already applied the MicroUpdate 1.1 fix? If that's the case then why did it try to download the MicroUpdate 1.1 (presumably to run it after successfully downloading it)?

Comment: I hear you, and I'll see why the message has the "or" condition in it. In the meantime, would you mind emailing me directly so I can send you instructions for collecting the full set of install logs? I can diagnose your problem from that information and see if there's something underlying this. You can reach me at eric.knox@microsoft.com

Comment: MicroUpdate 1.1 is a small number of bug fixes (4 I think) that we have discovered since we built and shipped Update 1 itself (which has many more bug fixes and features). So it's definitely something we recommend people have, but it's also a new process, so if we don't get 100% penetration of MicroUpdate on top of all Update 1 users, it's still ok simply b/c as a product, we're learning how to get these out successfully. It only really matters if you are impacted by one of the four bugs that it fixes.

Comment: Got it--any release notes for MicroUpdate 1.1 (hint, hint!)? Knowing my luck, I'm affected by all four bugs. :)

Comment: @Jazimov The four issues addressed seem to be described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9fe1e585-e0f5-4688-be35-6b133ac192e0

Comment: @AlexAngas is right...the link he pointed to says what is in MicroUpdate 1.1. And after a conversation with Jazimov, I verified that somehow, Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 was installed and then removed. That's why KB3110221 blocked...it really wasn't applicable on the machine. The real problem was how/why did VSUpdate 1 get uninstalled, and we did not figure that out.